# The class is not abstract and does not override abstract method getParentLogger() in javax.sql.Comm onDataSource?

Tags: java, maven, ant, java-8, java-6

I rework an old project that running under java 1.6 then it was rebuilt under the java 1.8.
No problem is compiled and make jar using ant.
Reworked project under maven.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

than

```
mvn clean package
```

I receive an error.

```
ThreadLocalDataSource is not abstract and does not override abstract method getParentLogger() in javax.sql.CommonDataSource
```

ThreadLocalDataSource - my class

Researched, that this method appeared only in jdk 1.7, but now the next question.

**Why using ant (jdk 1.8) I can make a jar, and using maven (jdk 1.8) - not?**

Thanks for the advice.

**UPDATE**
My Ant build-script:

```
<target name="prepare" description="Create build directories." unless="build.notRequired">
        <delete dir="${dist.dir}" failonerror="false" />
        <mkdir dir="${dist.dir}" />
      </target>
      <target name="build" description="Compile Java files and copy static files.">
        <if>
          <isset property="eclipse.home"/>
          <then>
            <property name="targetPlatformLocation" value="${eclipse.home}" />
          </then>
          <else>
            <property name="targetPlatformLocation" value="D:/WebEnv/eclipse-spring" />
          </else>
        </if>
        <getEclipseClasspath pathId="eclipse.classpath" targetPlatformLocation="${targetPlatformLocation}" workspace="${workspace}" projectName="${project.name}" />
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}" />
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" debug="true">
          <include name="**/*.java" />
          <classpath refid="eclipse.classpath" />
        </javac>
      </target>

      <target name="build.class.jar" unless="build.notRequired">  
         <if>
          <isset property="project.version.ebf"/>
          <then>
            <property name="metadataVersion" value="${project.version.major}.${project.version.minor}.${project.version.dev}.${project.version.ebf}" />
          </then>
          <else>
            <property name="metadataVersion" value="${project.version.major}.${project.version.minor}.${project.version.dev}" />
          </else>
        </if>  

        <copy todir="${build.dir}" preservelastmodified="yes" failonerror="false">
          <fileset dir="${res.dir}" includes="**/*.xml" />
        </copy>

        <tstamp />
        <!-- create a jar file for distribution -->
        <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/${project.name}.jar">

          <fileset refid="class.files" />
          <manifest>
            <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="${project.name}" />
            <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="${metadataVersion}_${DSTAMP}${TSTAMP}" />        
            <attribute name="Build-By" value="${user.name}" />
          </manifest>
        </jar>
      </target>


      <target name="build.jar" depends="build, prepare, build.class.jar">
        <!--<jar destfile="${dist.dir}/${project.name}-src.jar" basedir="${src.dir}" includes="**/*.java" />-->

        <copy file="${src.dir}/${project.name}-Context.xml" todir="${dist.dir}" preservelastmodified="yes" failonerror="false" />

        <copy todir="${dist.dir}" preservelastmodified="yes" failonerror="false">
          <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
            <include name="*.xsd" />
            <include name="${project.name}*.xml" />
          </fileset>
        </copy>


        <copy todir="${dist.dir}/web" preservelastmodified="yes" failonerror="false">
          <fileset dir="${web.dir}" />
        </copy>
      </target>
```

Comment: Could you share with us your ant build-script and maven config? I suppose, that Ant could use jdk1.6 instead.

Comment: Where configuration in ant can I this see?

Comment: As I could see, you don't use `source` parameter in `javac` task in Ant script. Are you sure, it uses new JDK when executes?

Comment: No, I'm not sure. Therefore I asked where to see which version of the compiler configuration in the ant?

Comment: Actually, when it's not set explicitly, it depends on a lot of things: your environment variables, version of JVM on which you run Ant, `compiler` attribute etc. Try to set it explicitly like `<javac source="1.8"...> ... </javac>` and check if it compiles your project.

Comment: Please tell me exactly where I should insert the <javac  parameter. Thanks.

Comment: In the eclipse default jdk 1.8

Comment: Inside target build find javac element.

Comment: That is only now found. How to change? I do not ant expert.
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}" debug="true">
      <include name="**/*.java" />
      <classpath refid="eclipse.classpath" />
    </javac>